# Is typedeffing templated base class to simplify the code a good practice?

Tags: c++, templates

I caught myself "inventing" this simple construct lately when working with many templated classes and deriving from them. I am not sure if it is common practice, or am I tying a rope around my neck.

`template <typename T> class Base {};`

```
template <typename T> class Derived : public Base<T>{
  typedef Base<T> Base;
};
```

I found it especially useful if the `Base` class has its own `typedef`s for some types. E.g:

```
template <typename T> class Base {
  typedef T Scalar;
  typedef Matrix<Scalar> Matrix;
};
```

Then it's easy to "import" types into the `Derived`. It saves re-typing the template signature. E.g:

```
template <typename T> class Derived : public Base<T>{
  typename Base<T>::Matrix yuck_yuck(); //that's what I am trying to simplify
  typedef typename Base<T> Base;
  typedef typename Base::Matrix Matrix;
  Matrix much_fun(); //looks way better
};
```

Also on of the big advantages is that, when you want to add another template parameter to the `Base` class. You don't have to go over a bunch of functions to change, just update the `typedef`. `much_fun` will have no problem if `Base` will be changed to `Base<T,U>` while `yuck_yuck` will need to have updated signatures (not sure if template parameter is formally included with the signature, so pardon me if I am making a formal error here, but I think it is).

Is this a good practice or am I playing with a gun next to my vital parts? It looks like it makes code more readable, and simplifies it, but maybe I am missing something that can backfire.

EDIT2: I got the working example. The `Base` class must be within its namespace or there will be conflicts with the same names within a scope, as the commenters pointed out. Below is the minimal example that embodies my real question.

```
namespace Fun {
template <typename T> class Base {
public:
  typedef T Scalar;
};
}

template <typename T> 
class Derived : public Fun::Base<T>{
public:
  typedef typename Fun::Base<T> Base;
  typedef typename Base::Scalar Scalar;
  typename Fun::Base<T>::Scalar yuck_yuck();
  Scalar much_fun();
};

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Derived<double> d;
    return 0;
}
```

With lots of stuff the code gets really bloated with `typenames`, and template parameters. But I already run into a trouble making up the example, by not placing `Base` in its own namespace. I wonder if there are any other caveats, that are actually killers to the idea.

Comment: The `typedef Base<T> Base` is a good idea. If there are a lot of template parameters you might also prefer `typedef typename Derived::Base Base`.

Comment: Does your compiler even let you do that? Mine doesn't.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I think I ate `typename` keyword.

Comment: However, `Base::Matrix` and `Base<T>::Matrix` shouldn't compile. You need to write `typename Base::Matrix`.

Comment: with g++ 4.8.1 : `typedef Base<T> Base;` gives `error: declaration of 'typedef class Base<T> Derived<T>::Base' [-fpermissive]`

Comment: Well my original code has something like this: `class SimpleGA : public RunEnvironment::Base<Specimen, StatsDataT>{
public:
    typedef typename RunEnvironment::Base<Specimen, StatsDataT> Base ; .....` and it does compile, I am not sure why my example does not =/ I am working on it, though. I basically `typedef` whole base class as `Base`.

Comment: Name should be different. `MyNamespace::Base<T> != Base` but `Base<T> == Base`...

Comment: @luk32 note that you can make that shorter with `typedef typename SimpleGA::Base Base`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thank you, putting base into a namespace worked. I got the working example. I apologize to everyone for the confusion.

Comment: Fun fact: You can use the injected-class-name of a template, and using-declarations instead of aliases/typedefs e.g. you can replace `typedef typename Base::Scalar Scalar;` by `using typename Derived::Base::Scalar;` (but that's unfortunately not always possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually consider it a helpful (and good) practice if the typedef is not exposed public or protected:

```
// No template, not Base, to avoid that discussion
class Derive : public SomeBaseClass 
{
   private:
   typedef SomeBaseClass Base;

   public:
   typedef Base::T T;

   T f();
}; 

class MoreDerived : public Derived
{
   // Base is not accessible
};
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is ill-formed, due to rule 2 of C++11 3.3.7/1

> A name N used in a class S shall refer to the same declaration in its context and when re-evaluated in the completed scope of S.

meaning that you can't use the name `Base` to refer to both the template and the typedef within the class scope. Certainly, my compiler won't accept it:

```
error: declaration of ‘typedef struct Base<T> Derived<T>::Base’ [-fpermissive]
error: changes meaning of ‘Base’ from ‘struct Base<T>’ [-fpermissive]
```

(NOTE: this refers to the simplified example originally posted, and doesn't cover the updated question where the base class name is in a different scope.)

Comment: I am sorry, I did not prepare the example correctly. The real code compiles. I put the `Base` into a namespace, like it is in the real code. I edited the question adding the example that compiles. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What compiler/version? This is a quite interesting issue with lookup inside templates, and I am not 100% sure that it should be reported as an error. If the class was not a template or the base was not a template, that typedef would have been perfectly fine.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: GCC, 4.6.3 and whatever [ideone](http://ideone.com/pkWUw2) uses (4.8.1?).

Comment: I see this answer gets lots of upvotes, but it really does not answer the question. Just helps to understand where I over-simplified my original example. The real code and current example is not ill-formed. It's my fault, but I think this kills my chances for the actuall answers. Well bummers =(

Comment: @luk32: It does tell you something important, if you are to do this, you should name the base type in a different way than `Base`. You cannot expect something to be called out as *good practice* when in many common uses (the base and the derived type are in the same namespace) it does not even compile!

Comment: @dyp: I am still stuck with 3 different C++03 compilers (and some of them old and awkward), so I don't quite get to exercise any *modern* features. Removed the misleading comment (for the record, I suggested `using Base<T>::Base;` to bring the injected name of the base into the derived object, seems to mean something different)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas That's sad :( I looked into the C++03 Standard and how g++4.8.1 and clang++3.5 in C++03 mode interpret this declaration, and it also seems to refer to the ctor, see [class.qual]. My suggestion `using typename Derived::Base;` is also rejected, though I don't quite understand why (in C++03). Edit: Saw your edit too late..

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Of course my real base class is named `Base` only because it sits within its own name scope. I think its ok like that. Nevertheless lesson learned. I didn't come into troubles with it ... until i "prepared" the simplified example. Also I don't expect it to be called a good pratice. I asked because it seems handy. I was more interested in drawbacks, like this. I also accept that this is a nice answer within this context. I understood it. Thanks.